# Plot for discrete time signal a^n in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot the discrete time signal in MATLAB:

```
x[n] = a^n for 0≤n≤6
```

Whenever I plot this function in MATLAB, it gives an error stating:-

```
Unrecognized function or variable 'a'
```

I would appreciate it if anyone could please let me know how shall I define 'a' in stem plot? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is variable ‘a’ supposed to be a specific value? Can’t really plot it if it’s unknown.

Comment: For the [stem plot function `stem()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stem.html), the simplest way is to have your variable `a` be a vector.
For your error, the variable `a` is not defined, so you will just have to define it as some vector you want. E.g. `a = 1:10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your value of `a` this will vary. In most cases you'll want to element-wise multiply using the `.*` so that matrix-multiplication is never accidentally performed. Below are three cases that might suit your use case.

[image: Output Results]

### Case 1: If `a` is a constant:

```
n = (0:6);
a = 2;
x = a.^n;
stem(n,x);
```

---

### Case 2: If `a` is dependent on `n`:

```
n = (0:6);
a = 0.5*n;
x = a.^n;
stem(n,x);
```

---

### Case 3: If `a` is another independent vector:

```
n = (0:6);
a = [0 5 7 9 2 4 2];
x = a.^n;
stem(n,x);
```